# QuickSort does not work well - Python 3

Tags: python, quicksort

I have a problem with QuickSort. He's ordering me the list but taking some items from me. I don't know what the mistake is.
I'd appreciate your help.

Code:

```
#QuickSort
def quickSort(lista):
    if len(lista) < 2:
        return lista
    menores, medio, mayores = _partition(lista)
    return quickSort(menores) + medio + quickSort(mayores)

def _partition(lista):
    pivote = lista[0]
    menores = []
    mayores = []
    for x in range(1,len(lista)-1):
        if lista[x] < pivote:
            menores.append(lista[x])
        else:
            mayores.append(lista[x])
    return menores, [pivote], mayores

L = [6,7,-1,0,5,2,3,8]
print(quickSort(L))
```

Result:

```
[-1, 0, 5, 6, 7]
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each call of `_partition` you drop the last element because you use

```
for x in range(1,len(lista)-1):
```

instead of

```
for x in range(1,len(lista)):
```

(`range(1,n)` gives `[1,2,...(n-1)]`)

Comment: You're absolutely right. True that range does not include the value of the length but takes up to (n-1). Thank you very much!